# How to write a program which can run on a computer without a operating system?

Tags: boot, system-installation, c, boot-loader, assembly

If there is a computer without operating system, then we can install one on it using a floppy disc or usb stick.  While the computer is booting, we push F11 or some other button, then the computer will boot from the usb stick and run the system installing program.
Now my question is that: How to write a program into the usb stick such that if we press the F11 button, the screen will print "Hello World!" or show some pictures.

How to realize such an program using C and assembly language?
 How to write such program into a usb stick?

Thaks

Comment: `floppy disc`? How old is this computer?

Comment: Have you looked at [this thread][1]?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22054750/1195751

Comment: @DevNull Thanks, that's exactly what i want

Comment: Ironically grub is an example of such a program.

Comment: Not directly related perhaps, but wrote a OL-logo thingy here: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19218/8014 , perhaps you can get some out of it. It is an MBR program of sorts ...

Comment: @Grub I posted my comment plus another example, as an answer, feel free to accept it if this answer your question. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't really have anything to do with Unix or Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, here is a thread that talks [bare metal programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054578/run-a-program-without-an-operating-system/22054750#22054750).

> General answer to the question: it can be done. It's often reffered to
>   as "bare metal programming". To read from flash drive, you want to
>   know what's USB, and you want to have some driver to work with this
>   USB. The program on this drive would also have to be in some
>   particular format. On some particular filesystem... This is something
>   that usually boot loaders do. Many ARM boards let you do some of those
>   things. Some have boot loader to help you with basic setup.

Here is another article with examples: http://www.valvers.com/open-software/raspberry-pi/step02-bare-metal-programming-in-c-pt2/